# WKWebView: trouble using evaluateJavaScript from remote URL requiring Basic Auth

Tags: ios, objective-c, authorization, wkwebview, javascript-injection

I have a remote JavaScript file that I would like to load from WKWebView. The dev Website the JavaScript file is on requires Basic Auth in order to Access.
The JavaScript file needs needs to load as a result of a button.
In otherwords, I can't use the WKUserScript injectionTime options.

I have two code examples. Both of them only half work. I can't test if the auth works without the EvaluateJavascript working, and I can't test the EvaluateJavascript function without the Basic Auth working... so... using WKWebView * webView...

```
NSString *authStr = @"username:password";
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Basic %@",[authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];

NSURL* jsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.xxxx.com/js/xxxxx.js"];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:jsURL];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

I can see the javascript in the webView window, but it is not being evaluated.

Then I have this other strategy:

```
     - (void)handleButton {
            NSURL* jsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.xxxx.com/js/xxxxx.js"];
            _scriptString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:jsURL usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        }

-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{
    if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0){
        NSURLCredentialPersistence persistence = NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession;
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username" password:@"password" persistence:persistence];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
        NSLog(@"in Auth");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%s: challenge.error = %@", __FUNCTION__, challenge.error);
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
    }
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
     NSLog(@"navigation complete");
    NSLog(@"scriptString %@", _scriptString); //Says UNAUTHORIZED
    if ([_scriptString length] > 0) {

        [_webView evaluateJavaScript:_scriptString completionHandler:^(NSString *result, NSError *evaluateError) {
            if (result == nil) {
                NSLog(@"no go dude: %@", evaluateError);
                return;
            }
            NSData *data = [result dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"i think it worked: @%", data);

        }];
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: So it looks like you're making using oauth and requesting a token in order to access your API? Why can you not check if your token is being properly returned?

Comment: I'm trying to use basic auth. If I'm requesting a token, I'm not sure how to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded the javascript URL in Safari on my iPhone, and entered the basic auth username and password into the popup. 
Then, this is the code that worked:

```
NSURL *jsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://username:password@dev.xxxx.com/js/xxxxxx.js"];
    NSString *injectedJS = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:jsURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    [_webView evaluateJavaScript:injectedJS completionHandler:nil];
```